# How does JSX interpolate props for elements with checkbox inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The below JSX works if `this.props.stocked` returns false or true but why doesn't it work if I just hardcode false in? As in replace it with `checked=false`

```
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.props.stocked}
        />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`checked=false` should be `checked={false}`

If you want to use a JavaScript expression as an attribute value, you have to wrap it in a pair of curly braces, otherwise you'll get a `SyntaxError`.

> Embedded: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX
>   text

You can read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#boolean-attributes)